# Как запустить два цикла foreach внутри одного html table в Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Имеется два таких запроса:

```
$query = $request->get('query');
    
    if (!$query) {
        $list1 = CounterAgent::where('visible', '=', true);
    }
    else {
        
        $list1 = CounterAgent::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('inn', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->where('visible', '=', true);
        
    }
    
    if ($district or $subject) {
        
        /* Сохраняем в сессию */
        $list = $list->where('subject_id', '=', $subject);
        
    }

    $amount_from = $request->get('amount_from');
    
    if (!$amount_from) {
        $list = Order::where('visible', '=', true)->orderBy('order_date', 'desc');
    }
    else {
        $list = Order::where('amount', '>', $amount_from)->where('visible', '=', true)
                ->orderBy('order_date', 'desc');
    }
    
    $list = $list->paginate(50);

    $list1 = $list1->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(50);
```

в шаблоне хочу вывести в одну таблицу но при объявлении двух циклов, таблица ломается, как их можно прописать?

```
    @foreach ($list1 as $rec)       
        <tr class="tr_{{ $rec->id }}">
            <td>
                <p>{{ date('d.m.Y (H:i)', strtotime($rec->order_date)) }}</p>
                <p>
                    @if ($rec->auction_date)
                        {{ date('d.m.Y (H:i)', strtotime($rec->auction_date)) }}
                    @else
                        &mdash;
                    @endif
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?//Компания {{ $rec->name }} (ИНН: {{ $rec->inn }})<br>//?>
                @if (!empty($rec->director))
                    {!! $rec->director !!}
                @else
                    &mdash;
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>{{ $rec->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $rec->bill }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ $rec->law_id }}
                <p>
                    @if ($rec->guarantee == 'working')
                        Исполнение
                    @endif
                    @if ($rec->guarantee == 'tender')
                        Тендер
                    @endif
                    @if ($rec->guarantee == 'guarantee')
                        Гарантийная
                    @endif
                    @if ($rec->guarantee == 'prepay')
                        Аванс
                    @endif
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>до {{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($rec->guarantee_expires)) }}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($rec->status == 'draft')
                    Черновик
                @else
                    Передано в банк
                @endif
            </td>
            @foreach ($list1 as $rec)
            <td width="200px">
                {{ $rec->name }}<br>
                <?// @if ($rec->type == 'company') [ Юридическое Лицо @else Индивидуальный Предприниматель @endif ]<br> //?>
                ИНН: {{ $rec->inn }}
                <?// <br>ОГРН: {{ $rec->ogrn }}// ?>
                {{ $rec->subjects }} {{ $rec->districts }}
            </td>
            <td width="200px">{{ $rec->address }}</td>
            <td>
                @if (!empty($rec->director))
                    {!! $rec->director !!}
                @else
                    {{ $rec->name }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! $rec->phones !!}
                <?// <p><a href="{{ route('admin_counter_agents') }}?vbank={{ $rec->id }}" class="vbank">VbankInfo</a></p> //?>
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! $rec->emails !!}
                <?// <p><a href="{{ route('admin_counter_agents') }}?vbank={{ $rec->id }}" class="vbank">VbankInfo</a></p> //?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внутрненний `@foreach` не там закрыт (за `</tr>`)

Comment: @Knyaz71 у меня получается кривой вывод, посмотрите пожалуйста